# Accesing internal webpage using google-map signed-in button

Tags: django, google-maps, authorization

The main webpage of my django server is a google map and I would like to use the signed=true button to give access to some gmail accounts to certain internal webpages.

My idea was to show a button according to whom was logged in using the google-map's signed-in button.

Can somebody give me some insights about if this is possible or what's the best to go with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the button you are talking about is part of the Google Maps Javascript API - see:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/signedin

Essentially the google maps sign in does not appear to offer user authentication that can be used with python. The python version of google maps  uses a server key that you set up for your app - see

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python

This is mainly for backend functions like reverse geoname loiokup.

That said, there is nothing to stop you retaining your no sign in google map but adding either google+ authentication or google openid authentication to your app.

Both of these authentications are available through the django-social-auth project.  This involves installing the python-social-auth app, syncing the database, adding appropriate oauth server details and adding the social auth project to you AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS setting.